# Recaptcha not working in IE7 and 8

Tags: javascript, ajax, recaptcha

I am using Google Recaptcha Ajax API and it is working well in FF and Chrome but a very disappointing result I got in IE 7 and 8. I follow guidelines via this link https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#AJAX

I got errors in IE **Unknown runtime error somewhere around line 103**. I use developer tool in IE to debug the errors. Well I have looked around the web and still can't find good solution yet. Hope anybody here can help me. Thanks.

Comment: And what is in and around line 103?

Comment: The debugger points to this line of code: Recaptcha.widget.innerHTML='<div id="recaptcha_area">'+d+"</div>"

Answer (score 0):

could you please try this 2 links

- http://drupal.org/node/1112080
- http://eventespresso.com/forums/2012/03/re-captcha-not-working-in-ie/

Answer (score 0):

Is your target for the ReCaptcha to be rendered a `<p>` by chance?

The recaptcha ajax creates divs and tables within the rendered element, and due to HTML rules (according to IE at least) these are invalid constructs, so they puke on it.